# Getting position of rendered image inside Image control

Tags: silverlight, image, windows-phone-7

I have an `Image` control with `Stretch==Uniform` which means larger images will be scaled down. In my case the `Image` control fills the whole client space, the scaled down image is being displayed centered inside the control. What now will happen: the size of the rendered image and the `Image` control do not have the same size - the `Image` control is usually larger than its content (since I use uniform stretching).

I now need to know the position of the actual image inside the `Image` control. Some background: the user can place a rectangle on the image to crop it. To match the rectangle with the image coordinates I need to know exactly where the image is.

Is there a way to determine the position of the rendered image inside the `Image` control? Or is the only solution to make the control the same size as the image content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get more control, you might want to put the image on a canvas inside a viewbox.

That way you get pixel control via the canvas, but a scaled view via the outer viewbox. Set the canvas dimensions to match the image and add any decorations to the canvas.

You may need to inverse-scale the rectangle stroke width so that it is visible when the canvas is small.